# Canvas reference

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I want to add a canvas to my application which I should be able to paint on. Sadly, I already fail at adding the reference. The MSDN page says the reference is `System.Windows.Controls` but I only can add the `System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon` reference.

How do I find the reference and am I even looking for the correct thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Canvas` class is in the `PresentationFramework` assembly.

You can find such information on MSDN.

Find the class you are looking for, in this case `System.Windows.Controls.Canvas` (just type this in Google). Then you will find this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> **Namespace:**   System.Windows.Controls
>
> **Assembly:**  PresentationFramework (in PresentationFramework.dll)

So you need to add a reference to the assembly `PresentationFramework` in your project, and create a `using System.Windows.Controls` in your code file.

Answer (score 1):

you can right click on your "references" and click "Add Reference...".
from Window that opens for you, click on "Assemblies => Framework => PresentationFramework " and add it to your project.

Maybe Helps You.